# Malware in magento site

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7 version for my store. Its worked fine . But from last 2 months its detected malware in site. When ever i browse any link open 4 popup with junk site. 
I have externally scanned my site via Foreginx , and they detect malware in my site www.coralconcept.in . I replaced current file system with previous file system which were working fine , but still i face the same scenario. I am attaching the report with this mail. Foreginx suggest me to upgrade the magento version. Will this fix this issue? If so then  how can i update my site magento version without negative impact?

I can not figure out the actual effected files . I never include direct JS / JQUERY files link in magento files. Foreginx also detect malware like onepage checkout , customer accout  etc. pages . Please help me out from this very uncomfortable condition ASAP.

Please see the attached scan report & suggest me what to do.

Thanks in advance[image: Forginx scan report]

Answer (score 1):

There are few steps require to get over from issue:

### 1.Server change:

May be sever have some security issue.So you need to change hosting.

### 2. Scan by Anti Virous

Download **the files  and folders from sever**,then scan those file & folder system by an anti-virous.So you can find the `malware effect files` .

**If found the issue,the remove malware code from  those files**

### 3.Upgrade the magento system

You should apply all **magento security patches or Upgrade magento system** at 1.9.3.1.

### 4. negative impact of Upgrade or apply patch

There are not negative impact will put at your system.but your Upgrade/patches should properly

Comment: Hello  I upgrade magento from 1.7.0.2  to 1.9.3.1 but still unwanted script generated in the head tag and displaying \n\r\n\r\ on the top of the page. Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: You can see it from www.myechoproject.com/coral